# Is it possible to print a list of values in MATLAB in color?

Tags: matlab

What I'm interested in specifically is this - I have a table of *results* (several arrays printed out) and would just like, for example to print in red the values which pass a certain value, or do not satisfy some other condition, whatever that may be.

Is something like that possible?

I'm afraid I use MATLAB only on odd days, so am not fully familiar with its capabilities. This may be something elemental to some of you.

Comment: Does Yair Altman's [cprintf](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window/) utility work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best method but you could display the text in a figure like this:

```
 figure
 axis([0 100 0 100])
 text(10, 90, 'Example of Red', 'color', 'r')
```

[image]

So perhaps you could use this and a combination of sprintf to print an array to the figure:

```
ar = rand(1, 10);
figure
axis([0 100 0 100])
for i = 1:length(ar)
    if (ar(i) > 0.5)
        text(10, 100-i*5, sprintf('%f', ar(i)), 'color', 'r') 
    else
        text(10, 100-i*5, sprintf('%f', ar(i)), 'color', 'g') 
    end
end
```

Gives you this:

[image]

Its a pretty complex way to do it, but if you have no other option right?

Comment: Common, is this not a great detailed answer to your problem?

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry for not getting back to you sooner. Your answer must've slipped me by. // Actually, I was hoping to print the values out, not in a figure, but in "text mode" (y'know, the regular mode in which you usually get values of variables and so on). Do you know whether it is possible to do it there?

Comment: Yeah, i know, i cant think of a way to do that, this answer was just another option in case you wanted. I think the comment under the question pretty much solves your problem.